# Bound on $L_p$ norm by the $L_1$norm

Tags: calculus, inequality, lp-spaces

For $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ and a measure $\gamma$ such that  $\gamma(\Omega)=1$, I saw a result which states that
$$\left(\int |x-y|^p d\gamma  \right)^{\frac{1}{p}} \leq diam(\Omega)^{\frac{p}{p-1}}\left(\int |x-y| d\gamma  \right)^{\frac{1}{p}} $$

I was trying to prove this for $p=2$ using Holders inequality, since $1=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}$ we have
$$\left(\int |x-y|^2 d\gamma  \right) \leq  \left(\int (|x-y|^{1/2})^2 d\gamma  \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \left(\int (|x-y|^{3/2})^2 d\gamma  \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} $$
But this doesn't give the desired inequality. Can anyone please figure out where I am making the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $\mathrm{diam}(\Omega)=\sup\limits_{x,y\in \Omega}|x-y|$.

Hence

$$\left(\int\limits_{\Omega} |x-y|^p d\gamma\right)^{1/p} \leq \sup\limits_{x,y\in \Omega}|x-y|^{\frac{p-1}{p}}\left(\int\limits_{\Omega} |x-y| d\gamma\right)^{1/p}\\=\mathrm{diam}(\Omega)^{\frac{p-1}{p}}\left(\int\limits_{\Omega} |x-y| d\gamma\right)^{1/p}
$$

Comment: Im not sure where we need $\gamma(\Omega)=1$ to be honest and I could not figure out how to to make $\mathrm{diam}(\Omega)^{p/(p-1)}$ out of  $\mathrm{diam}(\Omega)^{(p-1)/p}$